# Html onclick call local script with value

Tags: html, path

Currently I had created a html page with button which onclick on it will trigger local script. Each of the button were preset with the path of the script that will be triggered after onclick on the button.

However, the path are all fixed caused I need to duplicate the script with different configuration inside the script, For example, if there are 3 script (script A, script B, script C), my html page will also contain 3 buttons too with 3 different path.

```
<a href="C:\scriptA.bat"> -->First Html button will trigger this
<a href="C:\scriptB.bat"> -->Second Html button will trigger this
<a href="C:\scriptC.bat"> -->Third Html button will trigger this
```

Is there any way to pass value from the html onclick button into the script directly so the 'A','B','C' read by script directly? Possible pass arguments on network path?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify. Do you want to have just one script and pass some information to the script so it recognizes wich button was pressed?

Comment: Yea, correct, example first button will pass the value of 'A' into the script, so the script can read the value and use it as a configuration, hence no need to duplicate so much script with different path.

Comment: Well, I have never used bacth in this way so i cannot tell you if this is correct. I also dont have a windows machine  to test it. But the general idea is to call it with command line parameters like `C:\scriptA.bat param1 param2 etc` then this are read from the script like %1 %2 ... %9. look: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php